# Communication between remote service and activity android

Tags: android, service, android-activity, listener, sharedpreferences

I have an `Activity` and several remote services that should be running even if the Android app is not running. I need the services to listen for changes in the `SharedPreferences` of the main `Activity` (when this is running), but how can I do this?

`BroadcastReceiver`? IPC communication? Not sure..
Could you please give me a hand here?

Thanks a lot,
Manu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an Activity and several remote services that should be running even if the Android app is not running.

First, you do not need "several remote services" in the first place. At most, you need several services that are not remote. Being remote has absolutely nothing to do with "should be running even if the Android app is not running". You are wasting a lot of RAM, CPU, and battery this way.

Second, since neither the user nor the OS wants "several" services "running even if the Android app is not running", please try to consolidate them into one service and only have that service when it is *actively delivering value to the user*. For example, watching the clock tick is **NOT** actively delivering value to the user -- use `AlarmManager` for that.

> I need the services to listen for changes in the SharedPreferences of the main Activity (when this is running), but how can I do this?

Make them no longer be remote services, then have the service(s) register an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` with the `SharedPreferences` to find out about preference changes.

Comment: first, thanks a lot; great answer, because it lets me know that I might have some theoretical wrong concepts, as I though that remote service in Android were those that could be running even if the app was not running, while local services are "attached" somehow to the app, meaning that if the latter is killed or closed, the local services would stop running; is it this way?

Comment: If the user uses a task killer or the Settings application, they will kill all services, remote or otherwise. Beyond that, a service started with `startService()` will run until somebody calls `stopService()` or the service calls `stopSelf()`. Bear in mind that, due to developers leaking services, Android is getting increasingly aggressive about shutting down services on its own accord, without user intervention.

Comment: ok, just to be sure I should use local services: my app is supposed to log phone calls, sms and location and send them periodically to a remote server through PHP. But even if the user closes the app, the information should be sent all the time (every 24h for example, one connection that sends everything). Should I instead then user local services instead of remote?

Comment: You should not use remote services. You should use `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService`, where `AlarmManager` wakes up as needed (e.g., every 24h) to do the work. The `IntentService` will do that work on a background thread (which you need) and will automatically shut down when the work is done. Bear in mind that there is no documented and supported API for "sms".

Comment: hum ok, this means taking a step backwards 3 weeks but I will do it.. so the three "features" to log sms, calls and location should be in only one service? local :)

Comment: is there any resource I can take a look at like a tutorial or something about how to implement several services in one `Service` file?

Comment: @noloman: You don't have "several services in one `Service` file". You have one `Service` class in one Java source code file. It just happens to serve several roles, typically by examining the incoming `Intents` in `onStartCommand()` (and, if needed, `onBind()`) to determine what to do. You could use custom action strings or extras to indicate what operation you want performed.

Comment: what I do not understand is, if I should user `IntentService` instead of the `Service` class, should I use `onHandleIntent(intent)` or just the `onStartCommand()`? EDIT: I just realized this about `onStartCommand()` in the `IntentService` class: You should not override this method for your IntentService. Instead, override onHandleIntent(Intent), which the system calls when the IntentService receives a start request.

Comment: @noloman: Normally, you use `onHandleIntent()`. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in my previous comment.

Comment: when dealing with this, do I need to register a `BroadcastReceiver` or it isn't really necessary?

Comment: @noloman: That depends. If you are using a `_WAKEUP` alarm, then, yes, you need to use a `BroadcastReceiver`, perhaps in conjunction with my `WakefulIntentService`, so the device does not fall back asleep while you are trying to do your work. If you are not using a `_WAKEUP` alarm, then you can just use a `getService()` `PendingIntent` to send commands to your `IntentService` without a `BroadcastReceiver` middleman.

Comment: I have a concept about here: where should I call the method in the service that performs the updating of the remote server, in the BroadcastReceiver to call the method inside the service, or in the service itself in the onHandleIntent?

Comment: @noloman: In the service in `onHandleIntent()`. You may not have enough time in the `BroadcastRecevier`.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having a very serious concepts problem. I do not think I need the `BroadcastReceiver` as I do not need to pass anything back to my `Activity`, but without having a `PendingIntent`, I can't set an Alarm, right?

Comment: You do not necessarily need a `BroadcastReceiver` to use `AlarmManager`, as has been covered in these comments already. I will no longer be posting on this comment chain; please open fresh questions or seek other support avenues if you have further issues.